# having problem using ssd_inceptionv2 in colab ( error import tf_slim as slim ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'

Tags: python, tensorflow, using, solid-state-drive, coco

I have a `ModuleNotFoundError` while using the `ssd_inceprionv2` within colab.

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'
```

Here is what I've so far:

```py
%cd /content
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

!apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk

!pip install -q Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib

!pip install -q pycocotools

%cd /content/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

```py
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `tf_slim` is not installed on Colab.
Install `tf_slim` manually

```
!pip install tf_slim
```